# What does Promise.all actually do under the hood?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, resolve

I am trying to understand Promise.all here.
What I did here was to covert below code using Promise.all to achieve the same result.
I understand that Promise all combine the data1, data2.
My question here is that how does Promise.All work without resolve method?
Does Promise resolve those data within the method itself?

Please advise.

```
const readAllUsersChaining = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = [];
    getDataFromFilePromise(user1Path)
      .then((data) => {
        result.push(JSON.parse(data)); // what are you doing? he's gone mad...
        return getDataFromFilePromise(user2Path);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        result.push(JSON.parse(data));
        result ? resolve(result) : reject(result);
      });
  });
};
```

```
const readAllUsers = () => {
  const data1 = getDataFromFilePromise(user1Path);
  const data2 = getDataFromFilePromise(user2Path);
  console.log(data1, data2);
  return Promise.all([data1, data2]).then((data) => {
    return data.map((el) => JSON.parse(el));
  });
};
```

[image]

Comment: *"My question here is that how does Promise.All work without resolve method?"* Not quite sure what you mean. `Promise.all` simply creates a new promise internally that is resolved when all other promises are resolved.

Comment: It relies on the `.resolve()` calls that happen in the constituent promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` allows to wait until all promise passed as arguments to be fullfilled before the `then` method attach to be execute.

The real use case would be when you have to perform five call to an API, an you want to perform some treatement only when you have get the data from all the API call. you can rely on the `Promise.all` function which will wait all passed promised to be fullfilled for it to be fullfiled on it turn.

Bellow I provide an example of a `Promise.all` call. which has two Promises passed as argument. the first one has a timer which fullfilled it after 5 second and the second if fullfiled immediately but. the `Promise.all` will be fullfilled only when both of the promise passed as argument ar fullfilled

```js
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   setTimeout(()=> {
      return resolve({
          name: "First Promise"
       });
   }, 5000);
   
});

const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   return resolve({
      name: "Second Promise"
   });
})

const all = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

> My question here is that how does Promise.All work without resolve method?

Not quite sure what you mean. `Promise.all` simply creates a new promise internally that is resolved when all other promises are resolved.

Here is a simple implementation of `Promise.all` for the case that arguments are always promises:

```
function all(promises) {
  if (promises.length === 0) {
    return Promise.resolve([]);
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const results = [];
    let resolved = 0;
    promises.forEach((promise, i) => {
      promise.then(
        result => {
          results[i] = result;
          resolved++;
          if (resolved === promised.length) {
            resolve(results);
          }
        },
        error => reject(error)
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: hi @Felix Kling +1. It means that the individual promises can be resolved in any order, (which doesn't matter because the purpose of all() is to get promises in parallel), what really matters is that it returns an array with the results in the same order as we put them in the array, right?

Comment: @Coder23: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great @Felix Kling, thank you +1. I've learned a lot of with your posts, again thanks